# Flutter strange error saying that the previously deleted image file does not exist

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: image/icon2.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:675:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "image/icon2.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#66f5a(), name: "image/icon2.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

this is the error content

Even though I deleted the file called "image/icon2.png" in the error and replaced it with another image, an error appears.
There is currently no file named icon2.png in the image folder.
After upgrading the gradle version it became like this

I tried the below action, but it didn't work.

1. flutter doctor
2. flutter clean
3. Rerun after clearing cache
4. emulator data wipe

Comment: Can you share some code that shows where you are loading this image?

Comment: is your icon2.png a PNG file? Sounds like the PNG file is a renamed jpeg or other image filetype. download another png from google and try to replace the icon2.png with it.